# SonarQube: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to true

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code and I'm receiving a SonarQube Error: "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to false"

```
 private List<FileSchema> retrieveList(String sharepointUrl, String sharepointFolderPath, String sharepointFileName) {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Retrieving data from sharepoint file started on - {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = getHttpURLConnection(sharepointDomainUrl, sharepointFolderPath, sharepointFileName);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection !=null ? httpURLConnection.getInputStream() : null);
        CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(FileSchema.class)
                .withSeparator(',')
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .build();
        List<FileSchema> fileSchemaList = csvToBean.parse();
        return fileSchemaList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CSVException("Error occurred while reading the data from sharepoint CSV with message - {}", e);
    }
}


 private HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(String sharepointDomainUrl, String sharepointFolderPath, String sharepointFileName) {
    try {
        String token = authConfig.getBearerToken();
        setSystemProperties();
        String sharepointFilePath = sharepointDomainUrl + "/_api('" + sharepointFolderPath + "')/" + "Files('" + sharepointFileName + "')/$value";
        URL sharepointEndpoint = new URL(sharepointFilePath);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sharepointEndpoint.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        return urlConnection;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CSVException("Error occurred while retrieving the data from Sharepoint CSV with message - {}", e);
    }
}
```

SonarQube is giving an error on the line `httpURLConnection !=null`. Can anyone provide more insight into resolving this issue?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to add that null check in the first place? Your method `getHttpURLConnection` cannot return null as far as I can see and therefor checking if it returned `null` is totally pointless. And afaik that's pretty much what SonarQube is also telling you.

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re using null at all.  Do you expect `new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)` to succeed if a null Reader is passed to it?  These uses of null look like an attempt to circumvent exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to change it so doesn't check it for null.  As the first commenter pointed out, there's no way for it to be null, as simple inspection of the method that constructs it shows that it cannot return a non-null value.

Just make it:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

You might also consider combining this statement with the previous one, like this:

```
Reader reader =
    new InputStreamReader(getHttpURLConnection(sharepointDomainUrl,
                          sharepointFolderPath, sharepointFileName).getInputStream());
```